# wget does not use option in .wgetrc

Tags: wget, sles

I'm trying to specify a specific CA file for use with a proxy. When I use `wget --ca-certificate=file.cer`, it works fine. But when I try to put `ca_certificate = file.cer` in `$HOME/.wgetrc`, it doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
```

The [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html) say that these should both do the same thing, so I don't know what is causing the difference.

I'm on SLES 15 SP1 and using GNU Wget 1.20.3.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wgetrc Location manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Location.html)

> If the environmental variable `WGETRC` is set, Wget will try to load
> that file. Failing that, no further attempts will be made.
>
> If `WGETRC` is not set, Wget will try to load `$HOME/.wgetrc`.

So first thing to check is if `WGETRC` is set. If it is and is other than `$HOME/.wgetrc` then `wget` will not load latter.

> what is causing the difference.

I am not sure in relation to what is wget looking for files, so I would try using absolute path rather than relative.